# Connection Refused - Why does zookeeper tries to connect to localhost instead of a server ip

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, apache-zookeeper

My Reduce Tasks fail because all the namenode fails trying to connect to localhost instead of 10.10.187.170 ..

My application even tries to connect manually in the code..

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "10.10.187.170");
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
conf.set("hbase.master","10.10.187.170");
```

My hbase-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--Autogenerated by Cloudera CM on 2013-08-14T06:27:30.291Z-->
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://ip-10-10-187-170.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.client.write.buffer</name>
<value>2097152</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.client.pause</name>
<value>1000</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.client.retries.number</name>
<value>10</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.client.scanner.caching</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize</name>
<value>10485760</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name>
<value>60000</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.security.authentication</name>
<value>simple</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>zookeeper.session.timeout</name>
<value>60000</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
<value>/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>zookeeper.znode.rootserver</name>
<value>root-region-server</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
<value>ip-10-10-187-170.eu-west-1.compute.internal</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
<value>2181</value>
```

Error:

```
2013-08-24 20:05:36,213 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (Unable to locate a login configuration)
2013-08-24 20:05:36,213 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
```

Comment: Please try to use the ip-10-10-187-170.eu-west-1.compute.internal instead of the IP address in the conf object.

Comment: @JtheRocker Tried. Doesn't work.. namenodes just log this error message instead of logging something useful for me to debug..

Comment: Can you show how you use `Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();`? Do you use the `conf` to create a Job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out why it was connecting to the localhost.

I was having more than one configuration object to interact with 2 or more tables in HBase. Only for one of the conf object, i was setting the zookeeper quorum address. Didn't set it for the other objects.

By setting the zookeeper quorum address for all the objects did the trick.

Edit : Using only one conf object is more desirable(mapper or reducer). And by using it like

```
public void setup(Configuration conf) {
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "xxxxx");
}
```

The above code is easier to follow than having multiple objects which reduces HBase access time.